# Will I break a TOS by letting contacts login to a visualforce page I create

Tags: visualforce, customer-portal, authentication

Will I be breaking any TOS by giving contacts a username (email) and password (generated) to sign into a visualforce page to access an app I build. I want to do this without buying any customer portal licenses. I read a year or so ago that doing this would break salesforce TOS, and cause a violation that could end in being shutoff. I just need some clarification on what I can and cannot do regarding this use case.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's my understanding that custom authentication schemes invalidate the confidentiality clause of the Salesforce.com [Master Subscription Agreement](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://www.salesforce.com/assets/pdf/misc/salesforce_MSA.pdf&ei=-o7FUrf2JsXsoATuoIK4Dg&usg=AFQjCNHEL5oG27CRwXmGBTl7HGdwxrTTSA&bvm=bv.58187178,d.cGU) and thus would violate your TOS.

If you are building an app for the AppExchange, you would not pass security review.

Comment: TY. What about if I build an external site and authenticate via api?

Comment: Are you an ISV partner? This is typically a good question for your ISV rep.

Comment: You can use a standard login authentication mechanism, such as the Customer Portal licenses if you require a login for the site usage. Additional fees will apply.

Comment: No we're not. I had plans to write my acct manager about this, but I thought I'd SE it first. Thanks you've been helpful.